# calculating the average of elements in a tuple python

Tags: python

```
a=('A','1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1030')
b=('B', '-1.0', '1', '-2.443', '-1.456', '4.00', '3.00', '-2.343', '2.112', '3.00', '')
```

I want to exclude first element Ave B from a and b and calculate the averages of the values in a and b tuple. I was trying to write a code like this:

```
def avarage(value):
    sum=0
    value=list(value)
    first=value[0]
    value.pop(0)
    for i in value:
        sum+=i
    avrg=sum / (len(value))
    return avrg

print(avarage(a))
print(avarage(b))
```

I got a few mistakes like this and this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

How can I resolve this error or how can I find the average?

Comment: Uh oh, those are strings. Where is this data coming from?

Comment: You are iterating over a list of strings, `sum += int(i)`. Also, if you fancy, you can do the averaging in a one liner. `average = lambda x: sum(map(int, x[1:]))/(len(x)-1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
a=('A','1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1030')
b=('B', '-1.0', '1', '-2.443', '-1.456', '4.00', '3.00', '-2.343', '2.112', '3.00', '')

print sum(map(float, filter(None, a[1:])))/(len(a)-1)
print sum(map(float, filter(None, b[1:])))/(len(b)-1)
```

**Result:**

```
1026.4
0.587
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=('A','1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1030')
b=('B', '-1.0', '1', '-2.443', '-1.456', '4.00', '3.00', '-2.343', '2.112', '3.00',)

def avarage(value):
    sum=0
    value = list(value)
    value.pop(0)
    for i in value:
        sum+=float(i)
    avrg = sum / (len(value))
    return avrg

print(avarage(a))
print(avarage(b))
```

The problem was that the values in the list were still strings. To convert from a string to a number you need to use float()

Comment: when I edit the code as you show  I got an error like this:   sum+=float(i)     ValueError: could not convert string to float @JonathanDeWet

Comment: remove the last element from list B. It is not a number :) Sorry I forgot to mention that change

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` results when you are doing operations on unsupported datatypes.

[Python Docs link for `TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError)

In this particular scenario, the `TypeError` is raised cause you are trying to execute **addition** on two different datatype `String` and `Int/Float` without explicitly converting them to proper datatype.

```
def average(values):
     total = 0
     for element in values:
         if not element.isalpha() and element:
             total+=float(element)

     return total/len(values)
```

**Result**

```
a=('A','1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1030')
b=('B', '-1.0', '1', '-2.443', '-1.456', '4.00', '3.00', '-2.343', '2.112', '3.00',)

average(a)
933.0909090909091

average(b)
0.5336363636363637
```

If we are to only average over the numbers and not the strings, the function changes to

```
def average(values):
     total = 0
     total_values = 0
     for element in values:
         if not element.isalpha() and element:
             total_values+=1
             total+=float(element)

     return total/total_values
```

**Result**

```
average(a)
1026.4

average(b)
0.6522222222222223
```

Comment: `len(values)` counts also the excluded strings.

Comment: @Piinthesky
Yes, agreed, i kept it that way cause i am not sure if the the OP wants it that way or not!

Answer (score 0):

Error you got here because you are trying to add int and string type element here:

sum is int type element of value 0

and 
element in values are string type.

just replace:

```
sum+=i
```

with:

```
sum+=float(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I edit the code sum+=float(i) I got this error:       ValueError: could not convert string to float @rahul mehra

Comment: @seyazc I've just tried your above code with above replacement and the result was:1026.4
     0.652222222222
    [Finished in 0.0s]

Answer (score 0):

One more variation:

```
a=('A','1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029', '1030', '1030')
b=('B', '-1.0', '1', '-2.443', '-1.456', '4.00', '3.00', '-2.343', '2.112', '3.00', '')

def average(values):
  sum = 0
  count = 0
  for num in values:
    try:
      sum += float(num)
      count += 1
    except: pass
  return sum / count

print('%7.2f'%(average(a)))
print('%7.2f'%(average(b)))
```